# Using picker view with UIButton to open a new TableView

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a picker view and tableviews for each picker row programmed and I'd like to connect them via a UIButton. Any suggestions for a swift function to connect the Pickerview row with the botton to open that picker's table? (code below)
Thanks!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var Picker1: UIPickerView!

    var Array = ["G: Classroom friendly", "PG-13: Swear words OK(no sexual innuendo)", "R: Anything goes!"]



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        Picker1.delegate = self
        Picker1.dataSource = self

    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return Array[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return Array.count
    }

    public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    @IBAction func Submit(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    }
    @IBAction func ContinueBotton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
}



class ViewController1: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var ViewController1: UITableView!

    var GRating = [GN]()
```

Comment: "I have a picker view and tableviews for each picker row programmed and I'd like to connect them via a UIBotton." I have no idea what that means. What does "connect a picker view row with a botton to open a picker's table" mean?

Comment: (BTW, it's `UIButton`, not `UIBotton`.)

Comment: I'd like to have the row of the picker (G rating, PG13, R) correlate to a tableview of those options. So if you have the picker on G and click the button, the table view for G rating opens.

Comment: Don’t add buttons just utilise the `UIPickerViewDelegate` methods (didSelectRow)